# How to use canvas with Vue in component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas, vue-component

I'm tyring to add canvas to my Vue component this way, but it isn't work.

Result of code on screenshot. There is no erros and warnings in console.
[image: Result of code]

I tried to do get canvas `document.getElementById("canvas")` with `<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>` and it dosn't work too.

**How to use canvas in Vue component**?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <canvas
            ref="canvas"
        ></canvas>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'levelOne',
    data: () => ({
    }),
    methods:{
        func(){
            let cvn = this.$refs.canvas;
            let ctx = cvn.getContext("2d");  
            let bg = new Image();
            bg.src = "../assets/bg.png";
            bg.onload = function() {
                    ctx.drawImage(bg, 0 ,0);
            };
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.func();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: To clarify... Did you try `getElemetById` or `getElementById`? There's a small typo

Comment: @byxor I'm sorry, this is a typo only in question. I tried  `getElementById`

Comment: Perhaps you're fetching the canvas successfully, but the image isn't loading. Can you render other things on the canvas, like text? e.g. `ctx.font = '48px serif'; ctx.fillText('Hello world', 10, 50);`

Comment: @byxor, yes it's work for text, but where is a problem if path to `.png` is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try in this way:

```js
<script>
import myImage from "./assets/bg.png";

export default {
    name: 'levelOne',
    data: () => ({
    }),
    methods:{
        func(){
            let cvn = this.$refs.canvas;
            let ctx = cvn.getContext("2d");  
            let bg = new Image();
            bg.src = myImage;
            bg.onload = function() {
                    ctx.drawImage(bg, 0 ,0);
            };
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.func();
    }
}
</script>
```

or simply move your image within the `public` folder and then:

```
bg.src = "/bg.png";
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! But moving `bg.png` to the same folder stiil dosn't. You know why? This is very strange

Comment: do you mean the public folder? However, here you can find more informations: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling